# how to send two arrays to controller via ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I try to send two arrays to the controller, each array from a different class. But all I get is alert with an error message. What am I doing wrong? When I send only one array in ajax data, it is obtained fine in the first array of the controller.
my code js:

```
    $("#Button2").click(function () {
        var dict = new Array();
        $(":checkbox").each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked")== true) {

                var key = this.name 
                if ($("input[name = 'r" + key + "']").length) {                          
                    dict.push({
                        Code: key,
                        Reccomendation: $("input[name = 'r" + key + "']").prop("value"),                         
                    });
                }                                          
                else{
                    dict.push({
                        Code: key,
                        Reccomendation: $(this).prop("value"),                          
                    });

                }
            }

        }) //end function each
        var dict2 = new Array();

        dict2.push({
            Mentioned:  $("#yesno").val(),
            FollowUp: $("#Follo").val(),
            UpdateCode:5
        })


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("SavevisitSummary")",
        traditional: true,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { 'a': JSON.stringify(dict), 'b': JSON.stringify(dict2) },

        success: function () {
            alert("sucssec")

        },
        error:function(){
            alert("error")
        }
    })

 })
```

controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult SavevisitSummary(Reccomendations[] a, Summary[] b) { }
```

Comment: It has to be `data: JSON.stringify({ 'a': dict, 'b': dict2 }),`

Comment: You can also delete `traditional: true,` which is not applicable for arrays of complex objects)

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!! it realy work!